# Assigning pointers to allocatable derived type components in Fortran

Tags: arrays, pointers, fortran

I am new to Fortran and am developing a code in which I frequently do operations on two similar derived types (in this case representing models of particles in a scientific computing code). The two types are identical except one has only translational position and velocity components whereas the other also includes angular positions and velocities.

```
type(particle_A)
  real :: position(3)
  real :: velocity(3)
end type

type(particle_B)
  real :: position(6)
  real :: velocity(6)
end type
```

I have another derived type which groups arrays of both kinds of particles (together with some other data in the actual application):

```
type(particleGroup)
  type(particle_A), allocatable :: particleA_array(:)
  integer :: NparticlesA
  type(particle_B), allocatable :: particleB_array(:)
  integer :: NparticlesB
  character(len=30) :: particle_kind
end type
```

Where both arrays are allocated and re-allocated during runtime if more particles enter the simulation on this particular process. Depending on what `particle_kind` is set to (during initialization) I want to loop over one of these two arrays and call some subroutine (e.g. for updating the position and velocity). Something like this (in case of looping over the first array)

```
do iParticle = 1, nParticlesA
  call updateVelocity( particleGroup%particleA_array(iParticle) )
end do
```

and this for looping over the second array

```
do iParticle = 1, nParticlesB
  call updateVelocity( particleGroup%particleB_array(iParticle) )
end do
```

with the generic procedure `updateVelocity` implemented using an interface block.
Is there a way in Fortran to store which array to loop over during initialization (as a pointer?), so that I do not have to check `particle_kind` at every loop iteration? Or is there some better way of handling this problem?

Comment: I'm struggling to exactly understand what you want - when I do I strongly suspect my answer will use the words "type bound procedure" but I can't quite work out what you want at the moment. Would it be possible to write a short but complete code showing what you want to do?

Comment: Do you want to store information in both arrays and loop over both? Or only use one array at a time? Or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are only interested in using *either* `ParticleA` *or* `ParticleB` at runtime then you can achieve what you want using a polymorphic array.

You would first have to define a parent class, from which both `ParticleA` and `ParticleB` can inherit, something like

```
module Particle_module
  implicit none

  type, abstract :: Particle
  contains
    procedure(Particle_update_velocity), deferred :: update_velocity
  end type

  interface
    subroutine Particle_update_velocity(this)
      import Particle
      class(Particle), intent(inout) :: this
    end subroutine
  end interface
end module
```

Then you could write `ParticleA` as

```
module ParticleA_module
  use Particle_module
  implicit none

  type, extends(Particle) :: ParticleA
    real :: position(3)
    real :: velocity(3)
  contains
    procedure :: update_velocity => ParticleA_update_velocity
  end type
contains
  subroutine ParticleA_update_velocity(this)
    class(ParticleA), intent(inout) :: this

    ! ParticleA's update_velocity code goes here.
  end subroutine
end module
```

and analogously for `ParticleB`.

This would allow you to write `ParticleGroup` as having a single polymorphic array, which could be either of type `ParticleA` or `ParticleB` at runtime, something like

```
module ParticleGroup_module
  use Particle_module
  implicit none

  type :: ParticleGroup
    class(Particle), allocatable :: particles(:)
    integer :: no_particles
  contains
   procedure :: update_velocities => ParticleGroup_update_velocities
  end type
contains
  subroutine ParticleGroup_update_velocities(this)
    class(ParticleGroup), intent(inout) :: this

    integer :: i

    do i=1,this%no_particles
      call this%particles(i)%update_velocity()
    enddo
  end subroutine
end module
```

You could then use these classes like

```
program p
  use Particle_module
  use ParticleA_module
  use ParticleB_module
  use ParticleGroup_module
  implicit none

  type(ParticleGroup) :: particle_group

  ! Fill out the variables of `particle_group`.
  ! Note that the `%particles` array now has the concrete type of `ParticleA`.
  particle_group%particles = [ &
     & ParticleA([0., 0., 0.], [1., 2., 3.]), &
     & ParticleA([1., 1., 1.], [2., 3., 1.]) &
     & ]
  particle_group%no_particles = 2

  ! Call all the `update_velocity` subroutines.
  call particle_group%update_velocities()
end program
```

In simple examples, keeping `particle_group%no_particles` separately to `size(particle_group%particles)` is redundant, but I guess you might need it if you start doing more advanced memory-storage strategies (e.g. C++ std::vector-style storage).

Comment: This looping over a single array of either particleA or particleB is indeed exactly what I wanted so your answer fits perfectly, thanks!